# Change the colour of a ListPlot element in each iteration of Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, color

I would like to modify the colour of dots in a `ListPlot[Table[function]]`, e.g

```
Manipulate[
  ListPlot[Table[{co, se}, {n, nmax}], 
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Tiny},                   
    AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
  Style["Compacting the circle", 16, Bold],
  {{nmax, 5, "Nmax (step 5)"}, 5, 250, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Dynamic[
    ParametricPlot[{co, se}, {n, 1, nmax},
      ImageSize -> 300,
      AspectRatio -> 1]],
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

The `Manipulate` runs over the variable `nmax`, and the `ListPlot` runs over `n`. This means that when n`max` varies, the number of dots also varies.
What I want is to change the color of those dots when `nmax` varies.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough, but perhaps you could enhance it by adding some code (a minimal working example) and explaining what you want with more detail. (There are two confusing expressions in your question _"each iteration of Manipulate"_ and _"the variable running inside Manipulate"_)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and suggestions. I'll try to clarify my question including some code and rewording.

Comment: It sound like [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotStyle.html) is what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define `co` or `se` so I'll just substitute something random.  Use [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotStyle.html) to control the color.

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[{Cos[n], Sin[n]}, {n, nmax}], 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Tiny}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> If[nmax == 250, Red, Blue]],
 Style["Compacting the circle", 16, Bold],
 {{nmax, 5, "Nmax (step 5)"}, 5, 250, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Dynamic[ParametricPlot[{Cos[n], Sin[n]}, {n, 1, nmax}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1]], ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic example of what you probably mean, which lets you change the color of the plot with a simple control:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    Sin[x],
      {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
    PlotStyle -> color
  ],
  {color, ColorSlider}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you want is:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{Table[{Cos[2 Pi n/250], Sin[2 Pi n/250]}, {n, 250}], 
           Table[{Cos[2 Pi n/250], Sin[2 Pi n/250]}, {n, nmax}]},
           PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[PointSize[.02], Red]},
           AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
           Style["Compacting the circle", 16, Bold],
 {{nmax, 5, "Nmax (step 5)"}, 5, 250, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or this?

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[{Cos[2 Pi n/250], Sin[2 Pi n/250]}, {n, nmax}], 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Tiny}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[Sequence@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
 Style["Compacting the circle", 16, Bold], 
{{nmax, 5, "Nmax (step 5)"}, 5, 250, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Dynamic[ParametricPlot[{Cos[2 Pi n/250], Sin[2 Pi n/250]}, {n, 1,  nmax}, ImageSize -> 300, 
                        AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]], 
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want colored dots rather than a curve, I offer this variation. Note that `ListPlot` is not used. All the work of plotting the points along the circle is done by `Graphics` primitives. Sometimes this approach is easier than trying to force a built-in plotting function to jump through hoops it wasn't designed for.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    Table[{Hue[ArcTan[co[n], se[n]]/N[2 Pi]], Point@{co[n], se[n]}}, {n, nmax}],
    PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}},
    Axes -> True],
  Style["Compacting the circle", 16, Bold], 
  {{nmax, 5, "Nmax (step 5)"}, 5, 250, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  Dynamic@ParametricPlot[{co[n], se[n]}, {n, 0, nmax},
    ImageSize -> 300,
    PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}],
  ControlPlacement -> Left,
  Initialization :> (co[n_] := Cos[Pi n/125.]; se[n_] := Sin[Pi n/125.])]
```

[image: manip.png]